# Group homomorphism always exist between two groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there always exists a homomorphism between two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$? 
Why?

Answer (score 14):

If you require the homomorphism to be surjective, the answer is *no*; for example, there is no homomorphism of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, the cyclic group of order $3$, onto $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, the cyclic group of order $2$.

> **Added:** In particular, if $H:G_1\to G_2$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $$|G_2|=\frac{|G_1|}{|\ker h|}\;,$$ so $|G_2|$ must divide $|G_1|$. Another general class of examples for which the answer is *no* is provided by pairs of non-isomorphic groups of the same cardinality, like $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$, the cyclic group of order $4$, and $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2$, the [Klein four-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group): a surjective homomorphism between them would be an isomorphism.

If you do not require the homomorphism to be surjective, the answer is *yes*: just map every element of $G_1$ to the identity element of $G_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very useful.

Comment: Or, more generally, if you require the homomorphism to be *nontrivial*, then the answer is "not always".

Comment: your answer was very much helpful..what if we want our homomorphism to be injective?

Comment: @MansiTyagi: If $H:G_1\to G_2$ is an injective homomorphism, then $G_1$ and $H[G_1]$ are isomorphic groups. Thus, such an $H$ exists if and only if $G_1$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_2$.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianM.Scott for answering my question! That helped.

Comment: @MansiTyagi: You’re welcome; glad it helped!